# iPad UIModalPresentationFormSheet with UITabBarController's moreNavigationController edit mode issue

Tags: ipad, uitabbarcontroller

This is seemingly a bug, but i'm wondering if anyone can think of a workaround.

On iPad, you present a view controller as a UIModalPresentationFormSheet. This view controller is extending UITabBarController and has enough controllers to automatically display the "more" tab bar button.  Once you tap on the more button it will display the list correctly, but as soon as you tap on 'edit' it presents the edit view larger then the actual form sheet (cropped inside the form sheet), causing the content to be out of view, including the toolbar with the "done" button. The only way to dismiss is to force quit the app.

To verify that it's not something specific to my app I started a single view project, and presented a simple modal view. This modal view controller extends UITabBarController and has the following init method:

```
- (id)init {
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        self.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationFormSheet;
        NSMutableArray *controllers = [NSMutableArray array];
        for (int i = 0; i< 15; i++) {
            UIViewController *vc = [[UIViewController alloc] init];
            UINavigationController *nav = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:vc];
            vc.title = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"view %i", i];
            [controllers addObject:nav];
        }
        self.viewControllers = controllers;
    }
    return self;
}
```

I also tried adding the modalPresentationStyle to moreNavigationController with no change.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Good day, dizy.

A nice challenge you've made. Here is a solution, maybe it's a bit hardcore, but it works.

I've done as you wrote – subclassed UITabBarController and presented it as a modal view controller. And run into the same problem. When tapping "edit" button in "More" screen UITabBarCustomizeView appears and it's frame is inadequate.

So I've done the following. I've made MyModalTabBarVC a delegate of itself and implemented `tabBarController:willBeginCustomizingViewControllers:` method:

```
- (void)tabBarController:(UITabBarController *)tabBarController     
willBeginCustomizingViewControllers:(NSArray *)viewControllers
{
    UIView *modalView = self.view;
    CGRect bounds = modalView.bounds;

    UIView *customizationView   = [[modalView subviews] objectAtIndex:1];
    UIView *customizationNavBar = [[customizationView subviews] objectAtIndex:0];

    CGRect navBarFrame = [customizationNavBar frame];
    navBarFrame.size.width = bounds.size.width;
    customizationNavBar.frame = navBarFrame;
    customizationView.frame   = bounds;
}
```

So when this method is called `UITabBarCustomizeView` is already created. And a wrong frame can be changed manually. If you log `po [self.view subviews]` at the start you'll get:

```
(id) $1 = 0x06c6a940 <__NSArrayM 0x6c6a940>(
<UITransitionView: 0xd744ab0; frame = (0 0; 540 571); clipsToBounds = YES; autoresize = W+H; layer = <CALayer: 0xd744b50>>,
<UITabBarCustomizeView: 0x6c5e570; frame = (0 -384; 768 1004); animations = { position=<CABasicAnimation: 0x6c569a0>; }; layer = <CALayer: 0x6c618d0>>,
<UITabBar: 0xd744110; frame = (0 571; 540 49); autoresize = W+TM; layer = <CALayer: 0xd742b80>>,
)
```

PS. This solution doesn't fix animation. As you can see from log, corrupted animation is already created and charged. I hope that canceling it and adding a new one, appropriate, will not be a problem.

Answer (score 0):

The modal view's viewController must be causing the glitch.

### You could try to:

1. hide the tab bar while editing and un-hiding it when the done button
   is pressed.
2. create a custom toolbar for the view controller, this could be done
   with a UIView, so that it's set always be on top of the view.
3. resize your individual tabs. Best way to do this is to create your
   own custom tab bar with a UIViewController and IBActions connected
   to UIButtons with IBOutlets.

---

*Why would you have so many tabs in the modalPresentationStyle? I personally would use push segue instead.*

Try pushing to a new set of view controllers that are under their own navigation controller as well. There would be more room for the tab bar. To get back, put a back button in the toolbar that pops the push, or pushes back to the original.